# What is the difference between the two syntaxes in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

There is a table

```
mysql> select * from people;
```

| id | sex | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 남자 | 김준영 |
| 2 | 남자 | 박민수 |
| 3 | 여자 | 김영지 |
| 4 | 남자 | 이준수 |
| 5 | 남자 | 구준표 |
| 6 | 여자 | 이윤지 |
| 7 | 여자 | 이혜리 |
| 8 | 여자 | 권아영 |
| 9 | 여자 | 김예지 |
| 10 | 남자 | 이준필 |

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> select * from people where 0 and (select 1 union select 2);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from people where id=50 and (select 1 union select 2);
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I am solving SQL injection problem.
In the first case, the (select~) command is not executed due to '0 and' is already false.

I know 'logical operator short-circuit'

There is no column for id=50, why does the error occur in the case below?

Comment: You should not solve SQL injection like that. Solve it by compiling your SQL statements and bind the variables on the compiled statement.

Comment: it is just my local sql. for testing

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to how many programming languages work, an SQL engine is free to choose in which order the operands of an `AND` operator are evaluated. This decision is part of the execution plan that the engine designs for the query.

And it makes sense that the query returns without evaluating the subquery in the first case, since 0 is constant, and the engine does not need to access the data to know that there are not going to be results.

In the second case however, the engine *does* need to query the table for the first condition, as it does not know up front that there is no `id` with value 50. And as it has to really do a query for that, it will also take the subquery into consideration. As that subquery does not access any table, it is a good candidate to evaluate first. And that is when the engine finds out that it returns 2 records, which is invalid in that context.

As to your remark:

> I am solving SQL injection problem.

It is really bad practice to solve SQL injection like that. You should compile your SQL statement, and bind the variables to that compiled statement. That is how SQL injection is prevented in a reliable way.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

' select * from people where id = 9' 
If I run the query, system are looking for a row with id 9 while checking all records from the inside?

And what you're saying is that the above query itself causes errors in the execution stage, so the search itself doesn't even run?

Comment: The comment section is not intended for new questions, but you can see the execution plan if you prefix your SQL statement with `explain`. Whether or not the whole table needs to be scanned for finding a record with `id=9` depends on indexes. In the case where you got the error, the table is not accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is misleading, because what you are seeing has nothing to do with order of *evaluation*.  It has to do with the overall processing of the query.

SQL queries are processed in different steps.  The first step is *compiling* the query.  The second is *optimizing* the execution plan, and the third is *executing* the query.

During the optimization phase, MySQL checks for constant conditions in the `where` clause.  This is called *constant conditional removal* and is well [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html).

What happens in the first query is that MySQL sees the constant `0` in the condition, recognizes it as false, and (because all. the other conditions are `and`ed to it) replaces the `where` clause with `where 0`.  The second or additional conditions are not relevant, so they are removed.  The answer is known during compilation.

In the second case, MySQL has to actually look at the data.  There is no opportunity for such an optimization.

It is true that the order of evaluation of expressions during the execution phase is also left up to the optimizer.  However, that is not relevant to the question you have asked here.

I do strongly agree with the comment and sentiment that this is not the right way to solve any sort of SQL injection problem.  In fact, I don't really even see how it helps.  Use parameters.